# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'worker_threads' [React app]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I'm having an issue with a React app that works locally but fails when deployed to heroku. I suspect that the issue is related to my webpack file, perhaps worker_threads in particular. Below is the error in browser, my webpack file, and the warnings and errors in terminal.

I'm relatively new to coding so if I missed providing any vital info please let me know and I'd be happy to share or provide more screenshots.

Thank you in advance!

[**Browser Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSaO9.png)

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at application-2b6dd7d31a39824535633a8334b5a34672ad3c0786970547fef23234adf63ffb.js:11565:1283862)

[**webpack config**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A32Q.png)

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './frontend/trelloh.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '*'],
        fallback: {
            "fs": false
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react']
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name][md5:hash].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'webpack-assets/',
                            publicPath: 'assets/webpack-assets'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
};
```

[warning + errors 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Gt9.png)

[warning + errors 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsru6.png)

[warning + errors 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWFHt.png)

[warning + errors 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSSPH.png)